# Print out values of identical keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print out the values of 2 identical keys. But it is only printing out 1 value. How can I get it to print out the values twice?

```
alphaNum = {
"A": 1,
"B": 2,
"C": 3,
"D": 4,
}
prefix = ['C', 'C']
corr = []
for key in alphaNum:
    if key in prefix:
        corr.append(alphaNum[key])
print(corr)
```

Right now the program is printing [3] but I would like it to print [3, 3] since there are two 'C'

Comment: Instead of iterating over the keys of `alphaNum`, iterate over `prefix`…

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
corr = []
for key in prefix: # Iterate over prefix
    if key in alphaNum: # Check if key is in alphaNum
        corr.append(alphaNum[key]) # If it is, append to corr
print(corr)
```

Or, using a list comprehension:

```py
corr = [alphaNum[key] for key in prefix if key in alphaNum]
```